# Как вытащить количество комментарием к определенному посту?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Задача такая:
Django 2.2
Есть созданный пост и есть комментарии к этому посту, необходимо "вытащить" общее количество комментариев и показать в шаблоне. Ну и соответственно нужно что бы этот счетчик обновлялся при каждом новом комментарии.

Вот код:
**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    comments = models.ForeignKey(
        'Comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True, default='',
        related_name='post',
        verbose_name='Комментарии'
    )

    ...


class Comments(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True, default='',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        verbose_name='Автор: '
    )

    content = models.TextField(
        'Комментарий',
        blank=True,
        default=''
    )

    like = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        'Лайк',
        default=0,
        blank=True
    )

    dislike = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        'Дизлайки',
        default=0,
        blank=True
    )

    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(
        'Дата публикации',
        auto_now=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Автор: {self.author}, Дата публикации: {self.date_pub}'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post


def index_page(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
    }
    return render(request, 'news/index.html', context)
```

**Шаблон**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            {{ post.author }}
            <br>
            {{ post.date_pub }}
            <br>
            <br>
            <small>
                Просмотры: <span class="badge">{{ post.view_counter }}</span> |
                Комментарии: <span class="badge">{{ post.comments }}</span>
            </small>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ post.content|truncatewords:20 }}</p>
            <div class="mb-3">
                {% if user.is_authenticate %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                    Нравится <span class="badge badge-light">{{ post.like }}</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                    Не нравится <span class="badge badge-light">{{ post.dislike }}</span>
                </button>
                {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" disabled>
                    Нравится <span class="badge badge-light">{{ post.like }}</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" disabled>
                    Не нравится <span class="badge badge-light">{{ post.dislike }}</span>
                </button>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Ожидаемый результат:**
[image: Скрин с ожидаемым результатом]

Спасибо.

Comment: post.comments.count очевидно

Comment: @andreymal 7 Это было первое что я попробовал, но нет ((((

Comment: У вас неправильно отношение, `ForeignKey` должен быть из `Comments` на `Post`, да и имя модели стоит в единственное число привести.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, а можно подробнее? Что мне теперь исправить в Post? Я попробовал Ваш совет, но опять же ни чего (

Comment: Надо чтобы не пост ссылался на комментарий, а комментарии на пост. Какие тут ещё могут быть подробности?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev а в Post оставлять comments? Или его нужно убрать? Или изменить?

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar убрать

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev убрал, не работает (

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar потому что это не единственная ошибка в вашем коде. Просто самая большая. Вы руководство Django читали?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Да, но судя по всему не внимательно (((

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Все, разобрался...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Count

def index_page(request):
    posts = Post.objects.annotate(num_comments=Count('comments')).all()
    return render(request, 'news/index.html', {'posts': posts})
```

**index.html**

```
...
    Комментарии: <span class="badge">{{ post.num_comments }}</span>
...
```

Comment: У меня получилось по другому)

для Comment оставил models.ForeignKey ведущий на Post, а в Post добавил models.ManyToManyField ведущий на Comment

Comment: Небось что-нибудь вроде `{{ post.comments.count }}` или `{{ post.comments.all|length }}`?

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar ManyToManyField здесь это криво

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar и получили избыточные связи и медленные выборки.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, ага через post.comments.count. А почему излишние связи если я во views.py получаю все объекты Post... Или это как-то по другому работает?

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar связь типа ManyToMany нужна только тогда, когда один комментарий может принадлежать нескольким постам и один пост нескольким комментариям. У вас в базе сейчас создалась лишняя таблица хранящая записи отношений, а объединения в выборках теперь будут двухуровневыми. Кроме того, `post.comments.count` приведёт к _проблеме N+1_, для каждого поста будет сделан дополнительный запрос в базу, причём с использованием очень медленной функции `count`. После того, как будут опубликованы нескольких десятков новостей, ваш сайт просто ляжет.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Понял, принял, исправляю ))) Спасибо большое!!

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev скажите а как мне теперь вытащить все комментарии для это поста? Ну точнее я все не возьму в толк как теперь сделать так что бы под постом отобразить все привязанные к нему комментарии...

Comment: `{% for comment in post.comments.all %} {{ comment.content }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Спасибо большое!!! Я перепробовал многое, особенно post.comment, а вот на post.comment.all мозгов не хватило (

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar настоятельно рекомендую всё же перечитать руководство. Там все этим моменты в подробностях освещены.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Так читаю, решил прочитать все последовательно, а не по кускам...